# Edge split in Sverchok?

Tags: mesh, sverchok

You can have this effect by using Edge Split modifier, but can you achieve similar effect by using Sverchok?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer my own question:
Just found out that you can achieve that effect by using offset node in Sverchok.

Comment: polygon boom also works well